# How to update Ruby in Google SketchUp for Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, ruby, sketchup

Currently Google SketchUp for Mac has Ruby version `1.8.5` which I find a bit outdated. I can update Ruby to 1.8.7 (OSX's version) by the following commands

```
$ cd /Applications/Google\ SketchUp\ 7/SketchUp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current
$ ls
Headers/       Resources/     Ruby
$ ls Headers/
config.h  defines.h intern.h  missing.h ruby.h

$ rm -r Headers
$ ln -s  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Headers
$ ln -fs /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Ruby
```

SketchUp starts without problem and Ruby console shows version 1.8.7.

### 1.9.2

Now I try to go further and update to `1.9.2-rc2`. Google SketchUp requires `i386` binary, which can be produced by the following commands

```
$ cd ~/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/
$ ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386"  CFLAGS="-arch i386" LDFLAGS="-arch i386" ./configure  --with-arch=i386
$ make && sudo make install
```

Then I copy necessary files to SketchUp

```
$ cd /Applications/Google\ SketchUp\ 7/SketchUp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/
$ rm Headers Ruby

$ cp /usr/local/bin/ruby Ruby
$ mkdir Headers
$ cp /usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-darwin10.4.0/ruby/config.h Headers/
$ cp /usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h Headers/
$ cp -r /usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/* Headers/
$ ls Headers
backward/   defines.h   dl.h        intern.h    missing.h   re.h        ruby.h      util.h      vm.h
config.h    digest.h    encoding.h  io.h        oniguruma.h regex.h     st.h        version.h
```

and when I try to start SketchUp I get the following error report

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/A/Ruby
  Referenced from: /Applications/Google SketchUp 7/SketchUp.app/Contents/MacOS/SketchUp
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/Google SketchUp 7/SketchUp.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/A/Ruby: can't map
    /Applications/Google SketchUp 7/SketchUp.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/A/Ruby: can't map
    /usr/local/lib/Ruby: not a file
    /usr/lib/Ruby: not a file

Model: MacBookPro7,1, BootROM MBP71.0039.B05, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.62f5
```

Could you tell me why?

#### UPDATE1

Dan Rathbun [made some tests and found the following](http://groups.google.com/group/sketchupruby/browse_thread/thread/fc4278c7a2011582/a4e51c7970f165fa?hl=en&#a4e51c7970f165fa)

> On Win32 when I tried to get Sketchup
> to load any 1.9.x I got an "Entry
> point not found" for the ruby C
> function "rb_set_kcode" which is no
> longer in 1.9.x (it was renamed, and
> the Ruby people did not alias the old
> name to the new name.)
>
> Basically Sketchup calls rb_set_kcode
> to set the character encoding to UTF8
> just after loading the Ruby
> interpreter. It works fine for any
> Ruby in the 1.8.x branch, but in 1.9.x
> the Ruby project totally reengineered
> the character encoding, and gave all
> the C functions new identifiers, and
> added alot more functions.
>
> The solution for 1.9.x and Sketchup
> seems to be that Sketchup needs to be
> "Ruby Version Agile", which means a
> coding change by the Google Guys in
> Boulder.

Comment: *"...which I find a bit outdated."* For posterity, please expand on this. In your opinion, why would Google Sketchup gain from a Ruby upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

I addition to updating Ruby on your entire machine which can be especially painful and potentially destructive, another alternative would be to use RVM to manage specific versions of ruby.  This is especially good because updating ruby for your entire machine might cause any other application which relies on a specific version to break.

You should be able to easily make sketch up use RVM to fetch your specific ruby version thru a setting or directly if launched from the command line.

RVM http://beginrescueend.com/

There's also a [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/200-rails-3-beta-and-rvm) detailing how to install and manage RVM